# How to force postfix to deny all non TLS queries?

Tags: email, ssl, postfix, email-server, starttls

I have a server with `postfix` and a plain text authentication.

It accepts both TLS and non-TLS authentication.

**How can I force the server to deny all non TLS queries so that the mail users never send their username and passwords in clear text when login in?**

To make thinks clear, if `user2@mymailserver2.com` is the recipient and `user@mymailserver.com` the local sender:

- I want this command to work (since there is the `--tls` option):

  ```
  swaks --tls --to user2@mymailserver2.com --from -a user1@mymailserver1.com -auth CRAM-MD5 --auth-user user1@mymailserver1.com
  ```
- and that command to fail (since `--tls` is missing):

  ```
  swaks --to user2@mymailserver2.com --from -a user1@mymailserver1.com -auth CRAM-MD5 --auth-user user1@mymailserver1.com
  ```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because it's New Year's day once more Reading Manuals as a Service.

From the [manual](http://www.postfix.org/TLS_README.html#server_tls_auth)

> ## Supporting AUTH over TLS only
>
> Sending AUTH data over an unencrypted channel poses a security risk. When TLS layer encryption is required (`smtpd_tls_security_level = encrypt`), the Postfix SMTP server will announce and accept AUTH only after the TLS layer has been activated with STARTTLS. When TLS layer encryption is optional (`smtpd_tls_security_level = may`), it may however still be useful to only offer AUTH when TLS is active. To maintain compatibility with non-TLS clients, the default is to accept AUTH without encryption. **In order to change this behavior, set**
> `smtpd_tls_auth_only = yes`